# Altura de menú lateral de AdminLTE 100%

Tags: css, bootstrap, adminlte, card, height

> Buenas, me encuentro con el siguiente problema. No puedo configurar la altura de mi `card-body` a mi gusto.
>
> Tengo un `div card-body` dentro de un `div card`, dentro de un `section content` que a su vez esta dentro de un  `div content-wrapper` principal. Estoy usando `Bootstrap` y `AdminLTE 3.0`

Como pueden ver en el `div content-wrapper` puse el estilo `style="height: 100%;"`, probe eso, tanto en ese elemento como en otros, usando `min-height` y `max-height`, usando `px` y `vh` pero no cambia nada.

**Me gustaria que por defecto, el `card-body` utilizara el 100% de la altura del monitor. Muchas gracias**

```
<!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
<div class="content-wrapper" style="height: 100%;">
<!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
<section class="content-header">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row mb-2">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <h1>Remitos<small> - Viejo Almacén</small></h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <ol class="breadcrumb float-sm-right">

                    <li class="breadcrumb-item"><i class="far fa-id-card"></i></li>
                    <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Remitos</li>
                </ol>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</section>

<!-- Main content -->
<section class="content" style="min-height: 100%">

    <!-- Default box -->
    <div class="card" >
       
        <div class="card-body ">
            
                
        <!-- /.card-body -->
        </div>

        <div class="card-footer">
        
        </div>
                
        <!-- /.card-footer-->
    </div>
    <!-- /.card -->

</section>
<!-- /.content -->
```

> Adjunto imágenes de lo que actualmente veo en el sistema.

[image: Card-Body]

[image: Section Content]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No tiene mucho sentido, ya que esa acción desplazaría todo el contenido hacia abajo de la barra de tareas, pero las solución es usar `style="height: 100vh;"`.

Primero, debes eliminar el estilo `style="height: 100%;"` del `div class="content-wrapper"` y el `style="min-height: 100%"` del `section class="content"`.

Luego, empiezas a descartar agregando `style="height: 100vh;"` en `div class="card-body"`. Si no es lo que buscas, mueves el estilo a un `div` superior a la vez.

Comment: Si, tal cual. Hace un min respondi cualquier verdura porque me confundi de pregunta, pero tenes razon. Como nadie respondio ayer terminé solucionando exactamente como lo decis vos, con style="height: 100vh;" pero así y todo no me gusta como se ve en algunas resoluciones. Creo que voy a tener que hacer lo mismo que hice con el menu lateral, reacomodarle el tamaño una vez que la pagina se cargue por completo, mediante ``jquery``, porque toma un tamaño inicial que la plantilla (adminLTE) cambia en tiempo de ejecucion